# Implementing IEnumerable Interface

Tags: c#, interface

I know that IEnumerable is an interface, and I also know that when a class implements an interface it has to implement specific bodies for the methods in that interface. I've been writing a program recently and I felt that I need to implement the Ienumerable to one of my class so as to allow it to be used in a foreach loop. After I did so which is done this way:

```
class FData: IEnumerable<EClass> {

    // Removed the irrelevant contents
    public IEnumerator<EnumerableClass> GetEnumerator()
    {       
        for (int i = 0; i < Emp_Id.Count; i++) {
            yield return (new EnumerableClass { Emp_Id = Emp_Id[i], Salary = Salary[i] });
        }
    }
    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

I see that my FData class can be used exactly like a List as if it is inheriting all the enumerable methods such as Select(), All(), Any() ,etc.

I'd like to know how exactly does this happen if the behavior of these method are not defined in the interface ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All these methods are `extension` methods for types that implement the `IEnumerable` interface. So once a type implements `IEnumerable` has as methods also these methods - except the methods, that have been already defined inside the body of your type.

For further documentation, please have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Also, if you haven't before heard about `extension` methods, please first have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx).

Comment: There's no extension methods here.

Comment: @JonHanna what you mean?

Comment: I mean, your answer talks about extension methods, and links to a description of extension methods, but they have nothing to do with the question.

Comment: I totally understood what happened there, thank you so much for the answer.

Comment: @JonHanna why not? If I have understood correctly the question, Pierre ask how a custom class that implements the IEnumerable interface has access to methods like Select(), All() and so on. Since these methods are extension methods for all the types that implements this interface, why the above doesn't answer the question? Please explain me where I am wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Darn it. Yeah, +1. I totally misread something in a really silly way.

Comment: @JonHanna no problem at all Jon. I just got confused for a bit. no worries. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah, I shouldn't bother trying to look at this site when I've got a flu. I'm going to read some webcomics now instead :)

Answer (score 2):

They are extension methods and here's some more info.

Extension methods exist as static methods within static classes within some namespace and the first argument of the method includes the `this` keyword (see the example method signature below of `OfType`). In this case you are probably seeing the [System.Linq.Enumerable extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Bb345746%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). If you were to remove the `using System.Linq` namespace from your class file those extension methods would no longer be available. After market refactoring tools like Resharper will suggest extension methods where appropriate, but what you get out of the box in Visual Studio will not suggest extension methods (e.g. Ctrl+.). Therefore, if you want them you must make sure to add an appropriate `using` statement at the top of your class file. If you do not want them and do not need any other class in the namespace you can remove it and the extension methods will no longer be available.

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> OfType<TResult>(this IEnumerable source);
```

The beauty of this is that anything that implements `IEnumerable` will have the `OfType` method available so long as the namespace of that extension method is included. You can also make your own extension methods.